# Error while building android app

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-room

Application is being configured to use Room library, meanwhile studio requested for updating build numbers of support libraries and stopped at this error.

The log also has a warning for using java 8 as room-compiler uses only  Java 7 for processing. But, that has to be fine!!

App in not being built due to following issue:

```
Error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForStagingDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {@E:\Code\Android\Slave\VendorApp\Kwik24\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args2042478892032008870}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:471)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:319)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:88)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:85)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.visitEnd(LambdaDesugaring.java:150)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:401)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)
`
```

App gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**************"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

signingConfigs {
    release {

    }
    debug {
        storeFile file('../../debug.keystore')
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors { ******************************* }
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
//        debug{
//            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
//new libraries
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
//data persistence, android architecture library - Room
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0"

    }



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project gradle build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You have `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'`, which you should not. Include only the things that you need.

Comment: we use play services for lots of functionalities. There is part of gradle files which has been omitted for smaller display.

Answer (score 1):

I solved applying the solution suggested [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2384#issuecomment-376793947):

> So, I found, that for my Android Studio 3.1 with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0` and `gradle-4.4-all.zip` this issue resolving with adding `android.enableD8.desugaring = true` in gradle.properties file. Hope, it will help someone.

Comment: Exactly what i am looking for .Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when your build tools or sdk version is below from your other library gradle.

If you use a updated/latest library that use higher sdk or build tool version from your app sdk version, this type of error can happen... Change or update your sdk version and then see what happen

Answer (score 0):

You've probably have forgot to add `classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0"`
 in your root build.gradle file!